# Python One-hot encode every 2 characters in a text

Tags: python, dictionary, text, slice, one-hot-encoding

I have a custom alphabet as a dictionary consists of 2 letters keys and decimal values accordingly. I basically want to encode every 2 characters in text using this alphabet. The text cannot go beyond the given alphabet so it is kind of safe to define it manually. Here is what I did so far.

```
values = {'00' : 0.0, '01': 1.0, '02':2.0, '03':3.0, '04':4.0, '05':5.0, '06':6.0, '07':7.0, '08':8.0, '09':9.0, '0a':10, '0b':11, '0c':12, '0d':13, '0e':14}

sample = '000a'
indexes = [values[ch:ch+2] for ch in range(0,len(sample),2)]
```

The output should've been 0.010

However, I'm getting **unhashable type: 'slice'** type error by running this.

Is there another way to iterate over every two items in a text and replace them with the values in a dictionary? Or what would be the optimal way of doing this for more than 20G+ text files?

Comment: Do you mean hex-to-int conversion?

Comment: `values` is a dictionary. Inside your list comp you're doing something like `values[0:2]` - I *think* you meant to do: `[values[sample[ch:ch+2]] for ch in range(0,len(sample),2)]`. Then use `str.join` to concatenate the list elements into a string.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes. It is hex to int, but hex values are treated as the string type in the dataset.

Comment: @pault Yeap. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you describe in the example:

```
values = {'00' : 0.0, '01': 1.0, '02':2.0, '03':3.0, '04':4.0, '05':5.0, '06':6.0, '07':7.0, '08':8.0, '09':9.0, '0a':10, '0b':11, '0c':12, '0d':13, '0e':14}

sample = '000a'
indexes = ''.join(str(values[sample[ch:ch+2]]) for ch in range(0,len(sample),2))
```

I think you missed that `sample[:]` for `values` keys...